# Building set of n-bit numbers that have m bits are set and any two numbers in this set have distance 1

Tags: co.combinatorics

I want to build numbers set(one of possible) that meet following criteria

We are given **n**-bit numbers.
Select subset(**X**) of them that have exactly **m** bits set to 1.
Then I need to build subset(**Y**) of this set that meet following criteria:
1) For any number x and y(x!=y) in **Y**, (x & y) have exactly one bit set.
2) You can not extend **Y** with any new number from **X** so it still match (1) (Set **Y** is "full")

Given **n** and **m**, I need method to build set **Y** matching this criteria.
While there is multiple sets that can match this criteria i need method that can build only one set(any of matching)

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for **Y** to be as large as possible? You could just take **Y** to be those numbers that all have a single bit set, and otherwise have pairwise disjoint bits set. That is, for $m=3$, take 11100...0, 1001100...0, 10000110...0, etc.

Comment: You can think of the $n$-length bitstrings as representing subsets of an $n$-element universe ($x_i=1$ iff $i$ is in the subset). So you equivalently want a collection of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with pairwise intersection of size exactly one. Perhaps this has been studied?

Comment: usul: this is exactly what i am looking for